# linking to search bar in particular site

Tags: php

I want to link to search option in this website "http://rxindex.ru/" .Is there any PHP script so that user can type in form and when the form is submitted it is directly entered here in search bar in this website and searched.

Comment: Are you talking about HTML `<form></form>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the code you wanted:

```
<form action="http://rxindex.ru/" method="get">
    <input type="hidden" name="do" value="search" />
    <input type="hidden" name="subaction" value="search" />
    <input type="hidden" name="search_start" value="1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="full_search" value="0" />
    <input type="hidden" name="result_from" value="1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="result_num" value="20" />
    <input type="text" name="story" />
</form>
```

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/x5xhrap0/